# Retrieving Answer from Watson Discovery through a Search skill

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I have configured an `Assistant` with some **dialog skills**. The utterances are passed through `Node.JS` backend of my application. As a requirement for the project is to use `Discovery` but in term of a **search skill**.

My question is: When the request is proceed to a search skill from Watson, the way of returning the result from Discovery is the same like from a dialog skill e.g. `Discovery -> Watson Assistant -> Node.JS backend`?

(We didn't configure the billing plan yet, that's why I'm asking this basic question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Watson Discovery as part of a Watson Assistant search skill, access to Discovery is through Assistant. In terms of the underlying programming, take a look at the [Watson Assistant API overview](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-overview) in the docs and at the actual [V2 API for Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2). The [search integration is configured](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-search-add#skill-search-add-configure) is in Watson Assistant and determines how the results are displayed to the user as chatbot answer.

So, from the user view, everything is done through Watson Assistant.